# Typescript type incompatibility (Argument of type number not assignable to 1 | 2 | 3 | 4)?

Tags: javascript, typescript

This `Options` class has a factory function that returns a custom instance of the class.  This is it:

```
export class Options {
  quadrant?: 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 = 1;
  static factory(options: Partial<Options>): Options {
    const defaults: Options = new Options();
    return {
      ...defaults,
      ...options,
    };
  }
}
```

And I'm trying to pass in an factory function argument that modifies the `quadrant` like this:

```
export const defaults = {
  quadrant: 2,
};

const responsive: Options = Options.factory({
  ...defaults,
});
```

And it produces this error:

```
Argument of type '{ quadrant: number; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Partial<Options>'.
  Types of property 'quadrant' are incompatible.
    Type 'number' is not assignable to type '1 | 2 | 3 | 4'.(2345)
```

Is there way to fix this?

Comment: Because in your `defaults` object, the quadrant property is inferred to be `number`. Cast the object `as const` and the issue will be fixed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you hover over the `defaults`, you will see that the inferred type is `number` - you'll see something like this:

```
const defaults: { quadrant: number };
```

There are 2 ways to deal with this issue. You can either cast the defaults `as const`, meaning the type will be as follows:

```
export const defaults = { quadrant: 2 } as const;
// the type is "defaults: { readonly quadrant: 2 }"
```

The other way you can achieve what you want is actually type the `defaults` object so it's not inferred:

```
export const defaults = <Options>{ quadrant: 2 };
// or
export const defaults: Options = { quadrant: 2 };
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use a [`const` assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-4.html#const-assertions) when initializing `defaults` so that the type checker infers a more specific type for it: in particular, the type of the `quadrant` property will be inferred as the [literal type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#literal-types) `2` instead of the wider `number` type:

```
export const defaults = {
    quadrant: 2,
} as const;
/* const defaults: {
    readonly quadrant: 2;
} */
```

Which is enough to make your `Options.factory()` call work as expected:

```
const responsive: Options = Options.factory({
    ...defaults,
}); // okay
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBAYwDYEMDOa4HkwwJYQB2mA3gFACQAjgK4oAmUKhMA-AFxwCMcAPnACY+cAMzCALHAC83ANyU0MFPgRwAZigQxoATwAUEXAWKcACilh4USADw58RNAD4AlJ3vHSlCgkfx6wBo0SDBo7kaO0nCEwADu2BHEei7yFBRQwDA0UIRw5GkUAHTFAUEhaAA03kXFhg7EVWkAvqlNZG1kZKCQsIh+cKUowaFR+bQMTCycAlVNcOh9xDDyZAD0AFSLigOBQ+Wc5HBHcBkMREg6cOOMzDDT8nPrq52+SyfAaJDEeABuwOH1TAyDyOQoaLS6PT5YqFQbDSrtFJkIA)